# Why am I trying to kill people with a defibrilator?

Tags: battlefield-4

From time to time, especially when a teammate dies in my immediate proximity, my soldier decides to equip his defibrilator without my say-so. Often, this results in death, as the offender - the one who killed my mate - is still around and shooting at me, while I'm trying to "shoot" him with a defibrilator in hand.

What kind of feature is this, and how do I turn it off?
Obviously, I can't revive a friend when I'm dying, and he wouldn't want to be revived just to die again either.

Comment: What system version are you playing? This sounds like a setting somewhere or a very particular glitch that I have yet to hear much of.

Comment: @Dupree3 I'm playing on the PS4.

Comment: Well I'm sorry that you too have bought a system that the company has not made games for -_- alright I'll look into it

Comment: I have the same problem, i use a defib, drop a medkit, and hit Triangle (weapon switch buton) and it pulls out my defib again instead of my weapon. very annoying, and likely a bug

Comment: Looking like a new glitch, must have been caused by the most recent patch. Did not find anything with a decent google search.

Comment: I honestly, wholeheartedly spat at my screen from the sudden outburst of laughter. That title is hilarious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is this feature that if you press the use key on a revivable body, you will switch to defib, to a basic revive, and switch back to your weapon again.

Maybe its that? I'm looking for a better source on this, so maybe it can be deactivated.

[Reddit source](http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield_4/comments/1poyhl/psa_pressing_e_on_a_dead_body_will_swap_to_your/)

**Edit:**

[From the Battlelog forum:](https://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/en/forum/threadview/2955064775858525081/)

> If you press the use button, which is also reload button, over a downed teammate it will defib them and then switch back to weapon

Comment: I was guessing it was something to do with this "feature" however I didn't realise it reload/use was the same on the PS4.

Comment: I'm definitely going to have to try this out! That is a great feature.

Comment: So I'll just have to avoid reloading over my fallen comrade. It's good to know how the feature works, so it doesn't get me killed :D

Comment: I also didn't know that reload and use where the same button on PS4

Comment: For the record, this does not work in PC mode.  Tried with no luck.